# Dúvida gerando entidade a partir do código do arquivo cs no edmx C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Na versão do “.Net Framework 4” eu tenho um projeto que ao utilizar o .edmx fazia a geração automática do EdmSchema onde no meu projeto eu fazia assim:

1  - ADO – (Projeto Class Library)

2 – Arquivo .edmx

3 – Uma Interface

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LojaVirtual.DAO.Interfaces
{
    public interface IBaseCRUD<T>
    {

       void Adicionar(T pEntity);
       void Deletar(T pEntity);
       void Attach(T pEntity);
       void Detach(T pEntity);
       void Update(T pEntity);
       IQueryable<T> Selecionar(Expression<Func<T,bool>> where );
       IQueryable<T> SelecionarTodos();
       void Salvar();

    }
}
```

4 – Uma AbstratCrud:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using LojaVirtual.DAO.Interfaces;

namespace LojaVirtual.DAO
{
    public  abstract class AbstractCRUD<T> :IBaseCRUD<T> where T:class 
    {
        LOJAEntities loja = new LOJAEntities();



        public void Adicionar(T pEntity)
        {
            loja.AddObject(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
        }

        public void Deletar(T pEntity)
        {
            loja.DeleteObject(pEntity);
        }

        public void Attach(T pEntity)
        {
           loja.AttachTo(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
        }

        public void Detach(T pEntity)
        {
            loja.Detach(pEntity);
        }

        public void Update(T pEntity)
        {
            loja.ApplyCurrentValues<T>(pEntity.GetType().Name, pEntity);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Selecionar(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
           return loja.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(where);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> SelecionarTodos()
        {
            return loja.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }

        public void Salvar()
        {
            loja.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Na versão do “.Net Framework 4.5” tenho a mesma estrutura, mais , o meu AbstractCRUD não consegue acessar as informações do IBaseCRUD

Erro:

> Error CS1061  'CRUD_MVCEntities' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'CRUD_MVCEntities' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   DAL C:\Users\nome\Downloads\Projeto.FileInput\DAL\AbstractCRUD.cs   15  Active

Alguém sabe o porque? 
Agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Esses método, `AddObject` e `DeleteObject`, são utilizados em versões mais antigas do **EF** e pertencem ao `ObjectContext`, mas em EF6, por exemplo, trabalhamos com um `DbContext`, que tem uma forma diferente de gerir a informação.

Terá que adaptar o seu código para usar o `DbContext`:

```
public abstract class AbstractCRUD<C, T> : IBaseCRUD<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
{
    private C _entities = new C();

    public C Context
    {
        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ListarTodos()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ProcurarPor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public void Adicionar(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remover(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Editar(T entity)
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Gravar()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Agora é só uma questão de fazer as adaptações que quiser, mas em princípio funcionará sem problemas.